# Interval of $p$ that makes the $p$ power of a function integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For a measurable real-valued function $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ let $P(f):=\{p\in(0,\infty):|f|^p\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\lambda)\}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Show that for every subinterval $J$ of $(0,\infty)$, which may be open or closed on the left and on the right, there is some $f$ such that $P(f)=J$. *Hint*: Consider functions such as $x^a|\log x|^b$ on $(0,1]$ and on $[1,\infty)$, where $b=0$ unless $a=-1$.

I don't understand the hint. $f(x)=x^a\notin\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ for any $a$. The log part is also not integrable:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 & \int_0^\infty x^{-1}|\log x|^bdx \\
= & \int_0^\infty |\log x|^bd\log x \\
= & \int_0^1 (-\log x)^bd\log x+\int_1^\infty (\log x)^bd\log x \\
= & \int_{-\infty}^0 (-x)^bdx+\int_0^\infty x^bdx \\
= & -\int_{-\infty}^0 (-x)^bd(-x)+\int_0^\infty x^bdx \\
= & -\int_\infty^0 x^bdx+\int_0^\infty x^bdx \\
= & \int_0^\infty x^bdx+\int_0^\infty x^bdx \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But for $J=(0,\infty)$, I can find such a $f(x)$:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x-1 &\text{$1<x\leq2$}\\
3-x &\text{$2<x\leq3$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: The hint is asking you to consider a piecewise function which equals $x^a |log^b(x)|$ on one interval (either $(0, 1)$ or $(1, \infty)$) and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: @MarkSaving The hint still doesn't help. a piecewise function which equals $x^a|\log x|^b$ on either $(0,1)$ or $(1,\infty)$ and 0 elsewhere either has $P(f)=(0,\infty)$ or $P(f)=\emptyset$. Raising a power function to a positive power is still a power function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) For $J=(c,\infty)$, we just let $f(x)=x^{-1/c}$ for $x\in[1,\infty)$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere. If $p=c$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}dx=\log x|_1^\infty=\infty.
\end{equation}
If $p>c$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_1^\infty x^{-p/c}dx=\frac{x^{1-p/c}}{1-p/c}|_1^\infty=\frac{\infty^{1-p/c}-1}{1-p/c}=\frac{-1}{1-p/c}.
\end{equation}
Thus $P(f)=(c,\infty)$.

(2) For $J=(0,c)$, we just let $f(x)=x^{-1/c}$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere. If $p=c$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx=\log x|_0^1=\infty.
\end{equation}
If $p<c$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_0^1 x^{-p/c}dx=\frac{x^{1-p/c}}{1-p/c}|_0^1=\frac{1-0^{1-p/c}}{1-p/c}=\frac{1}{1-p/c}.
\end{equation}
Thus $P(f)=(0,c)$.

(3) For $J=(c,d)$, we just let $f(x)=x^{-1/c}$ for $x\in[1,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^{-1/d}$ for $x\in(0,1]$, and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere.

(4) For $J=[c,\infty)$, we just let $f(x)=x^{-1/c}(\log x)^{-2/c}$ for $x\in[e,\infty)$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere. Let $t=\log x$, then $e^t=x$ and $e^tdt=dx$.
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_e^\infty x^{-p/c}(\log x)^{-2p/c}dx=\int_1^\infty t^{-2p/c}e^{(1-p/c)t}dt.
\end{equation}
If $p=c$, then $|f(x)|^p\in\mathcal{L}^1$ since
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_1^\infty t^{-2}dt.
\end{equation}
If $p>c$, then $|f(x)|^p\in\mathcal{L}^1$ since
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_1^\infty t^{-2p/c}e^{(1-p/c)t}dt<\int_1^\infty t^{-2p/c}dt<\int_1^\infty t^{-2}dt.
\end{equation}
If $p<c$, then $|f(x)|^p\not\in\mathcal{L}^1$ since, using Taylor's series, and letting $r=1-p/c$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx & =\int_1^\infty t^{-2(1-r)}e^{rt}dt \\
& >\int_1^\infty t^{-2(1-r)}(1+rt+r^2t^2/2)dt \\
 & >\int_1^\infty t^{-2(1-r)}r^2t^2/2dt \\
 & =\int_1^\infty t^{2r}r^2/2dt.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus $P(f)=[c,\infty)$.

(5) For $J=(0,c]$, we just let $f(x)=x^{1/c}(-\log x)^{-\frac{2}{c}}$ for $x\in(0,e^{-1}]$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere. Let $t=-\log x$, then $e^{-t}=x$ and $-e^{-t}dt=dx$.
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_0^{e^{-1}} x^{p/c}(-\log x)^{-\frac{2p}{c}}dx=\int_1^\infty t^{-\frac{2p}{c}}e^{(-1+p/c)t}dt.
\end{equation}
If $p=c$, then $|f(x)|^p\in\mathcal{L}^1$ since
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx=\int_1^\infty t^{-2}dt.
\end{equation}
If $p<c$, then $|f(x)|^p\in\mathcal{L}^1$ since, using Taylor's series, and letting $r=1-\frac{p}{c}$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx & =\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t^{2(1-r)}e^{rt}}dt<\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t^{2(1-r)}(1+rt+r^2t^2/2)}dt \\
 & <\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t^{2(1-r)}r^2t^2/2}dt=\int_1^\infty\frac{2}{t^{2+2(1-r)}r^2}dt<\frac{2}{r^2}\int_1^\infty t^{-2}dt
\end{split}
\end{equation}

If $p>c$, then $|f(x)|^p\not\in\mathcal{L}^1$ since, using Taylor's series, and letting $r=\frac{p}{c}-1$ and $n$ be an integer satisfying $n-2(1+r)\geq-1$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx & =\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{rt}}{t^{2(1+r)}}dt>\int_1^\infty\frac{1+rt+r^2t^2/2+\cdots+r^nt^n/n!}{t^{2(1+r)}}dt \\
 & >\int_1^\infty\frac{r^nt^n/n!}{t^{2(1+r)}}dt=\frac{r^n}{n!}\int_1^\infty t^{n-2(1+r)}dt\geq\frac{n!}{r^n}\int_1^\infty t^{-1}dt
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus $P(f)=(0,c]$.

(6) For $J=[c,d]$, we just let $f(x)=x^{-1/c}(\log x)^{-2/c}$ for $x\in[e,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^{1/d}(-\log x)^{-\frac{2}{d}}$ for $x\in(0,e^{-1}]$, and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere.

(7) For $J=(c,d]$, we just let $f(x)=x^{-1/c}$ for $x\in[1,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^{1/d}(-\log x)^{-\frac{2}{d}}$ for $x\in(0,e^{-1}]$, and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere.

(8) For $J=[c,d)$, we just let $f(x)=x^{-1/c}(\log x)^{-2/c}$ for $x\in[e,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^{-1/d}$ for $x\in(0,1]$, and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere.